# MAMP - Document root wont work properly

Tags: apache, mamp

MAMP - Document root won't work properly It only display one of my other projects, even If I change the root directory to my current project it just displays the same project as before. I can't change it at all no matter what I do, I have reinstalled MAMP 4 and MAMP 3. No matter what I do there is the same problem? CAN ANYONE HELP!!

Comment: where did you change the `Document Root`? and did you restart the server?

Comment: I'm pointing the document root to a project folder on my desktop, I have  restarted my apache server via terminal (sudo apachectl restart) but the root directory still points to another of my projects the same one all the time can't seem to change it, even removed and reinstall MAMP but still same problem, What do you think? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This not `DocumentRoot` issue it's `Directory` issue because of **MAMP** use `Apache 2.2.32`. `Apache2.2` and `Apache2.4` are different `Vhost` format. **MAMP** version [history](https://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/).

**Apache 2.2 Vhost format**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**Apache 2.4 Vhost format**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/Library/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/Library/docs/dummy-host2.example.com">
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

[Apache Vhost format reference](https://serversforhackers.com/c/configuring-apache-virtual-hosts).

If you use **MAMP** your issue will not solve. Try `Apache 2.4`. If you are [Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/) user then use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). If you are [Mac](https://www.apple.com/lae/mac/) user then use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

Comment: It is working for me I just delete my cache history and reinstall Mamp thanks for your help